# What exactly is a Client library?

Tags: client-library

This sounds like a very general question, what does it mean when people say they are building "client libraries" or they have "client generators" for different programming languages?

Answer (score 3):

Not exact definition, but for understanding purpose, we say a client library is a collection of code specific to one programming language that makes it easier to use an API. Which enables by providing tools and an abstraction layer, letting developer to construct queries and use response data without having to create HTTP requests or process HTTP responses by hand.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Open Client Client-Library Migration Guide > Understanding Client-Library](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36065.1550/html/ctlibmig/X55077.htm):

> **Client-Library** is an applications programming interface (API) for use in writing client applications. Client-Library provides generic
>   building blocks for constructing distributed client applications,
>   including non-database applications.

Comment: Would you happen to have some examples so I can solidify my understanding? Thanks!

Comment: @blee908 It will vary for different language

Comment: That explanation of "client libraries" is about as useful as this explanation of a car: "A car is a mechanical machine for use in creating machines that act like cars. Cars are composed of mechanical building blocks constructed for human distribution, goods location, including livestock".

Answer (score 0):

Normally API is referring as Client libraries.

Comment: So API = Client Libraries? They are synonymous?